# Checking multiple types in Python to throw exceptions

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I'm manually trying exceptions to fully comprehend them and I have created a code as follows:

```
def misterio(a,b):
    if type(a) or type(b) != ("int") and ("float"):
        raise TypeError ("Arguments should be numbers" .format(a,b))
    else:

        if (b<0):
            raise ValueError ("B cant be 0")
        elif (b==1):
            return a
        else:
            return a+misterio(a,b-1)

print(misterio(3,2))
print(misterio(3,"a"))
print(misterio(3,1))
```

But it doesn't get pass the first `if`. All I want to do is check if my arguments are numbers, (I know `b` should be at least greater than 1, but I'm doing it step by step). Is there a way to do this in the most pythonic way? Cause I yet don't understand why it doesn't get past the first `if`, even if both are `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
def misterio(a, b):
    if not all(isinstance(x, (int, float)) for x in [a, b]):
        raise TypeError("Arguments should be numbers.")
    else:

        if (b < 0):
            raise ValueError("B cant be 0")
        elif (b == 1):
            return a
        else:
            return a + misterio(a, b - 1)


print(misterio(3, 2))
print(misterio(3, "a"))
print(misterio(3, 1))
```

---

First, use `isinstance(...)` instead of `type(...)` and second:

```
if type(a) or ...
```

returns always true, even if `a` is `None`:

```
a = None

if type(a) or None:
    print("Yes")
```

Not related to your actual error but you did not use `a` or `b` in the error message, so I left it out.